# Create custom entity for response with Web Api .NET

Tags: .net, api, generics, entity, response

i working with web api in .NET c#, but i dont understand the differents responses... Becouse,  I'm trying to create a standard to synchronize my services it with the front end (ajax calls from javascript)...

i create the next entity:

```
public class CustomResponse<T>
{
    public bool isValid { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public T data { get; set; }

    public CustomResponse()
    {

    }

    public CustomResponse(bool isValid, string message, T data)
    {
        this.isValid = isValid;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public CustomResponse(bool isValid, string message)
    {
        this.isValid = isValid;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

in controllers

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("all")]
    public CustomResponse<List<Client>> All()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = bllClients.All();
            return new CustomResponse<Client>(true, "sucessful", result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new CustomResponse<Client>(false, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Then in client JS:

```
function getAll() {
   $.ajax({
       ....
       ....
      success: function(data) {
         if(data.isValid) {
           //do something
         } else {
            alert(data.message);
         }
      }
   });
}
```

Is valid this options ??? 
or there is some more optimal way

Comment: What happened when you tried? Did you get the response you wanted?

Comment: yes my friend, I just want to know if it's the right way to do it, or is there a better way? opr example: return IhttpAction Result, return only entity, HttpResponseMessage etc ...

Comment: "Best" all depends on what you are trying to do. You will have to describe what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

why not use IHttpActionResult ?

like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("all")]
public IHttpActionResult All()
{
    try
    {
        var result = bllClients.All();
        return Ok(result)
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex); 
    }
}
```

for more info check this article:
https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/http-status-codes-in-asp-net-web-api-a-guided-tour/